# CSS: how do I have a border-bottom on table rows, except for the last row

Tags: css

I have a variable number of table rows (n), and I would like the border bottom to apply to rows 0..(n-1)

how do I do that?

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You have two options: (1) adding a specialized class in the HTML to the last row; or (2) using the `:last-child` pseudo class in your CSS.

#### Option 1: Specialized Class

If you can apply classes to your HTML, you can add a specialized class to the final row. If your markup is being generated by a server-side script (eg. a PHP script), you will need to edit that script to add similar markup.

HTML:

```
<table>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
   <tr class="last">
      <td>
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
table
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr
{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
tr.last
{
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

#### Option 2: CSS Pseudo Class

The alternative is to use the `:last-child` CSS pseudo class. Using the `:last-child` class doesn't require any changes to the HTML and so may be a better choice if you aren't able to change the HTML. The CSS is almost identical to the above:

CSS:

```
table
{
   border-collapse:collapse;
}
tr
{
   border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
}
tr:last-child
{
   border-bottom: none;
}
```

The drawback of this approach is that [versions of Internet Explorer before 9 don't support](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/contents.html#t35) the `:last-child` pseudo class.

Comment: I have a variable number of rows. So, I have no idea when the last row is. =\

Comment: @DerNalia, if you have a dynamic number of rows you've got a server-side, or client-side, script generating them. I'd suggest tagging the question with that language that so that we can help you implement @KP's first suggestion. As `:last-child {border-bottom: 0 none transparent;` (or similar) is the only pure-css option.

Comment: If your ok with not using pure css, then your generating script could apply class="last" to the last generated element.

Answer (score 27):

I know this is an old question, but it's worth mentioning that now with CSS3 all you have to do is us the `not()` selector in your CSS, like this:

```
tr:not(:last-child) {
    border-bottom: 1px solid #E3E3E3;
}
```

Comment: yes but it removes the border from the last tr of thead

Comment: @BenjaminSeche Easily avoided: only select `tr` elements that are children of `tbody`.  Something like `table>tbody>tr:not(:last-child)` should do the trick.

Answer (score 16):

```
tr:last-child td {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Saves you putting a class on the last tag.

Answer (score 6):

this is used with any class call in html

```
tr:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this way

```
table tr:not(:last-of-type) { border-bottom: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using jQuery you can use the following script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".tableClass tr:not(:last) > td").css('border-bottom', ' 1px solid #DDD');
});
```

Comment: you do not need jQuery for this, same selector pure css will work: `.tableClass tr:not(:last) > td { border-bottom: 1px solid #DDD; }`

Comment: One of the most annoying things is when a front-end "developer" uses jQuery to make up for their lack of CSS knowledge.